# "Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch" error trying to group a many to many relationship

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, many-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm new to CoreData and I'm playing a bit with it for future projects.

I'm trying to show a list of Songs grouped by his/her Singer. A Song can be sing by many Singers and a Singer can Sing many Songs :-) That's my model:

[image]

Then I have a many to many relationship.

When I try to set the sectionNameKeyPath to songSingers.name it crash with the error:

```
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch: (songSingers.name)'
```

Why I am receiving this error? Here are some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addDummyData];

    NSError *anyError = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&anyError];

    if( !success ) NSLog(@"Error = %@", anyError);
}

- (void)addDummyData
{
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"Song"];
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"Singer"];
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"Lyric"];

    // Lyrics
    Lyric *l = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lyric" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
    l.name = @"Lyric 1";

    // Songs
    Song *s = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    s.name = @"Song 1";

    Song *s2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    s2.name = @"Song 2";

    Song *s3 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    s3.name = @"Song 3";

    // Singers
    Singer *sg = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Singer" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    sg.name = @"Singer 1";

    Singer *sg2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Singer" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    sg2.name = @"Singer 2";

    // Relations
    sg.singerSongs  = [NSSet setWithObjects:s, s2, nil];
    sg2.singerSongs = [NSSet setWithObjects:s2, s3, nil];

    s.songSingers   =  [NSSet setWithObjects:sg, nil];    
    s2.songSingers  =  [NSSet setWithObjects:sg, sg2, nil];
    s3.songSingers = [NSSet setWithObjects:sg2, nil];    

    s.songLyric = l;
    s2.songLyric = l;


    NSError *anyError = nil;
    BOOL success = [managedObjectContext save:&anyError];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", anyError);
    }

}
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController) 
    {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Song" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

        NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" 
                                                                       ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *singerDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"songSingers.name" 
                                                                       ascending:YES];

                                                                         ascending:YES];        

        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameDescriptor,nil]];

        NSString *sectionNameKeyPath = @"songSingers.name";

        NSFetchedResultsController *myFetchedResultsController
            = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                              managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath 
                                                         cacheName:nil];


        myFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = myFetchedResultsController;
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Singer" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *anyError = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                  error:&anyError];
    Singer *sg = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section];
    return sg.name; 

}
```

You can see my dummy data 'addDummyData'  I think is well defined :^P

- Song 1 and 2 are for Singer 1
- Song 2 is for Singer 2 too
- Song 3 is for Singer 2

Thank you